# App still following .sks file after I deleted it

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios8

I’m playing with Sprite Kit in iOS 8. I changed the `.sks` file included (added some sprites, etc.), and it reflected when I ran the app. But then I deleted the `.sks` file to work directly on `GameScene.swift` but when I ran the app, the changes I made to the `.sks` file still showed up. I even emptied the trash and deleted the app from the simulator to make sure it rebuilds afresh, with the same results. What can I do?

Comment: You didn't say if you cleaned your project build or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean your project by clicking Product -> Clean in Xcode. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you selected "Move to Trash" and not "Remove Reference" when you deleted it.